# Send push notifications in java

Tags: java, push-notification

I have developed a cross platform application with an Android client and a Mac desktop client. I want to send a push notification to my Mac client from my Android Client. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do that? Typically, how does any push notification server, send a push notification to the client? Which protocol is used to send push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Java Client for Apple Push Notifications](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)?

It's used for the most common use cases and can be configured easily.